# C++ Win32api output Unicode from user's input

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

I realize there may be similar questions, but I have been really stuck for a while now. I'm operating on Windows 10 using C++ and the Win32 API.

I need to read a user textbox for a hexadecimal code, something like `Ѱ` or `U+0470`, although the 'U+' is not going to be present. After receiving this value, I need to take the code and print the appropriate symbol.

Using the code below I can print any Unicode symbol:

```cpp
createWindow(L"Static", L"\u2230", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 10,10, 190,40, hWnd, NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

I can also read the textbox using `GetWindowText()`. However, I can not figure out how to get the user's input `0470` and print this as a Unicode character in the textbox.

Comment: `I can not figure out how to the user's input 0470`  Which api are you going to use to accept user input?

Comment: For the record and clarification, I'm using the win32api and I am already familiar with printing basic text.  I just needed a way to convert the hexadecimal to the appropriate Unicode and format for printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convert the string `L"0470"` into a number. It's a base-16 number, so you'd use `std::wcstoul` from `<cwchar>`. You can then cast this number to a WCHAR. I assume you know how to turn a single character into a string.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It turns out wcstoul is exactly what I was missing.

Comment: Well it sounds like you should accept the answer then ;)